# preg_split (regex)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, symfony, doctrine-orm

how can I get a data of Array type as a TextArea in a Symfony form ? :

I tried this :

```
$suggest = $table->getSuggestion;

/* its format in database is : 
s:378:"# first_suggest
# second_suggest
# third_suggest 
*/

$suggest = preg_split("/# (.*)[\n\r]*/", $suggest, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$table->setSuggestion($suggest);
```

& so it's shown in the textarea field as :

```
#first suggestion 
#second suggestion
#third suggestion
```

but in the database it seems as following :

```
a:8:{i:0;s:32:"first_suggest
";i:1;s:47:"second_suggest
";i:2;s:45:"third_suggest";}
```

which means :

```
array:42 [▼
  0 => "first_suggest\r"
  1 => "second_suggest \r"
  2 => "third_suggest \r"
]
```

instead of :

```
a:8:{i:0;s:32:"first_suggest";i:1;s:47:"second_suggest";i:2;s:45:"third_suggest";}
```

& I don't know where is the problem here, can you help me please ?!

Comment: You know that this is a serialized string?!

Comment: So, why not use `"/# ([^\n\r]*)[\n\r]*/"` if you do not want `\r` to get matched?